# What is the wrong with subquery while insert existing records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**Exception :**

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

am getting above exception just am trying to insert one row using already inserted one row
records.Please help me to solve this problem.

```
insert into RDT_ATTACHMENTS  values
((select  MAX(id) from RDT_ATTACHMENTS),1363,(select fname,fpath,fsize,description,refentity,uploadby,uploadon,
      originalfname,LATEST   from RDT_ATTACHMENTS where id = 68))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the VALUES keyword

```
INSERT INTO RDT_ATTACHMENTS
SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM RDT_ATTACHMENTS), 
        1363,
        fname,
        fpath,
        fsize,
        description,
        refentity,
        uploadby,
        uploadon,
        originalfname,
        LATEST   
FROM RDT_ATTACHMENTS 
WHERE id = 68
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this query:

```
insert into RDT_ATTACHMENTS
select  
    MAX(id) over(), -- (SELECT MAX(id) FROM RDT_ATTACHMENTS) to get the max(id) of table
    1363, 
    fname,
    fpath,
    fsize,
    description,
    refentity,
    uploadby,
    uploadon,
    originalfname,
    LATEST   
from RDT_ATTACHMENTS
where id = 68
```

Provided table `RDT_ATTACHMENTS` has the same number of columns in the select in the same order.

Comment: MAX (id) OVER() will always return 68, because SELECT/OVER() triggered after the WHERE clause.

Comment: yes I manually inserted but I didn't ask that in Question.That is primary key.

Comment: btw, +1 for modified answer;)